# Is there a way to checkout git repository, to certain folder with maven?

Tags: java, git, maven, protocol-buffers, mvn-repo

I am attempting to automatize download of repository containing only protocol-buffers (with structure), to "resource" folder for later processing.

I need this kind of functionality, to keep my `*.proto` files separated from c++ and java code, as they are technically not connected with each other (java application is used for debugging).

My desired effect is to at least checkout repo into project — 
My dreamed effect is to get this repo updated every time I run maven.

BR

Comment: Sounds like a job for a CI solution like Jenkins?

Comment: Not really. I am using separate repo for `.proto` definitions, to allow people working on c++ project edit it and commit. Due to this, I do not have to keep copying files there and forth. At this moment I have to do this manually, while In c++ code I can use CMake to handle it for me (fetch every build, and rebuild if changed).

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at `git submodule` allowing you to embed one versioned repository within another. If you only care about the "latest" then enable `submodule.recurse`. Maven wouldn't need any special handling at all...

Comment: I've never knew about this functionality. This is a great suggestion! You should write answer so I could accept it! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

After working a lot with such a problem, I found personally that the git submodule might be a solution for you (if you are not using svn).

---

Okay, so after googling, I have came across this: [maven-scm-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/index.html), which even from description solves my request.

To save time for most people I will paste example of usage, to make it work.

You need to add this to your pom structure:

```
<project>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:[YOUR_PROJECT_URL]</connection>
    </scm>
    
    <--! second part -->

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                <!-- YOUR PATH HERE -->
                <checkoutDirectory>src/main/resources/meta</checkoutDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tag</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>tag</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</project>
```